# Adding ScrollBar in Kotlin class

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollbar

I am having trouble `ScrollBar` it shows error when I add it in a Kotlin class. Import library is also showing an error. What should I do? Below is the code:

```
import android.widget.Toast
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.ScrollBar
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_pdf.view.*


import java.io.File

class PDF_Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf)


        val pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView) as PDFView

        val scrollBar = findViewById<ScrollBar>(R.id.scrollBar)
        pdfView.setScrollBar(scrollBar)

        scrollBar.setHorizontal(false)

        val i = this.intent
        val path = i.extras!!.getString("PATH")


        val file = File(path!!)

        if (file.canRead()) {


            pdfView.fromFile(file).defaultPage(1).onLoad { nbPages -> Toast.makeText(this@PDF_Activity, nbPages.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }.load()

        }
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what errors you're getting?

Comment: import library of scrollbar,scrollbar in findviewbyid and setScrollbar these are showing errors

Comment: Well did you add it to the dependencies in your build.gradle? `compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:1.6.0'`?

Comment: yes i have added 2.8.2 version

Comment: add your xml code.

Comment: And build.gradle and *exactly* what the errors are.

Comment: i think it is working now after changing the dependency version to 1.6.0

Comment: add your xml code because i kotlin provide features then why you used findViewById . i think error in xml code.